# Need help to line progress with animation in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have couple of row and each row have a state and states are (Waiting, in-progress, done). Also each row have a title, imageView, topLine and a bottomLine.

Depending on state of the row, I need to animate the line progress and change the image in imageView with animation.

Till now I have done the image change in imageView with animation but it's not perfect. It's showing animation while scrolling. Also, I tried line progress animation with UIBezierPath, but not succeed. It's fluctuate while scrolling. [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIvos.png)

I want to achieve, line will draw with a animation and image will change on that time only while line are animating on the cell. It should not fluctuate while we scroll the tableView.

Some code reference

In cellForRowAtindexPath

```
 let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnimationTableViewCell") as? AnimationTableViewCell

        // code block without animation. Only image animation done but its not perfect
        /*switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let firstIndex = 0
            let nextIndex = 1
            cell?.animateFrom(first: arrItem[firstIndex], to: arrItem[nextIndex])
        case arrItem.count - 1:
            let currentIndex = indexPath.row
            let prevIndex = currentIndex - 1
            cell?.animateFrom(previous: arrItem[prevIndex], to: arrItem[currentIndex])
        default:
            let currentIndex = indexPath.row
            let prevIndex = currentIndex - 1
            let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
            cell?.animate(previous: arrItem[prevIndex], current: arrItem[currentIndex], next: arrItem[nextIndex])
        }
        cell?.changeImageWithAnimation(arrItem[indexPath.row].state, row: indexPath.row)*/

        // code block with improper animation
        if (cell?.shapeLayer == nil) {
            cell?.doAnimation(state: arrItem[indexPath.row].state, row: indexPath.row, isFirstTime: firstTime)
        }
        cell?.lblTitle.text = arrItem[indexPath.row].title
        cell?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell!
```

in AnimationTableViewCell

```
func doAnimation(state: ProgressType, row: Int = 0, isFirstTime: Bool) {

        NSLog("\(row)")

        guard isFirstTime else {
            return
        }
//        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: <#T##DispatchTime#>, execute: <#T##() -> Void#>)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: (DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(row))) {

            self.shapeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

            // create whatever path you want

            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.lblTopLine.frame.origin.x, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.lblTopLine.frame.origin.x, y: 74))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.lblTopLine.frame.origin.x, y: 148))

            // create shape layer for that path

            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = state.color().cgColor
            //        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

            // animate it

            self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.duration = 1
            shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")

//             save shape layer

            self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
//                self.lblTopLine.backgroundColor = state.color()
//                self.lblBottomLine.backgroundColor = state.color()
//                self.shapeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
            })

            self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "initial")
            self.imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(250), execute: {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    self.imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                })

                UIView.transition(with: self.imgView, duration: 0.5, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "tick")
                }, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

You can download sample project from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tftirbxtrw8v1bh/ProgressAnimation.zip?dl=0).